# New Nokia Phones in bad reception areas

Tags: 8.0, lumia, cellular-data, nokia-lumia-1020, cellular

So me and few friends at work use to have a Nokia Lumia 900 using at&t.  The area where I work didn't have the best coverage, maybe 2 bars of LTE outside and when on the first floor of the building we would get no signal at all(911 calls only).  Most of it was because of a building blocking the signal, even though Sprint and Verizon received pretty good coverage.

Now Nokia Lumia phone was not the only one having this issue with at&t, no matter the phone(Android, iPhone etc) no one would get a signal at all.

Then one day at&t did some work on one of their towers and all at&t phones started to get coverage, including my Nokia 900.

So April I went out and bought me the Nokia Lumia 1520 and noticed I started getting no signal again.  Sometimes it would even tell me I had 2 bars of LTE, but wouldn't be able to go to any websites.

However, the iPhone, Android and even the Nokia Lumia 900 users were able to get 2 or 3 bars of LTE when I was not getting no signal at all.

Thinking it was my phone, I took my wife phone to work, which is a Nokia Lumia 1020 and she was having the same problem.

Another friend of mine bought a Nokia Lumia 1520 and he is having the same issue.

I called Nokia about the poor reception, and they said it's not a problem with the phone but the reception in the area or the SIM card.  I tried to explain to the technician that all other at&t phones were not having this issue, even older Lumia phones; I even tried explaining other newer Lumia phones were having the same issue.  He wouldn't listen, just kept telling me it's not a problem with the phone.

Does anyone know if newer Nokia Lumia phones have a poor radio or is it a software/firmware issue?  If it's a software/firmware issue, how can I get Nokia/Microsoft to listen?

Comment: If anything, my lumia 1020 gets better reception than my htc titan or lumua 800, so may just be down to your local geography

Comment: I wonder why local geography affect the newer Lumia from getting worse reception than older Lumia devices?

Comment: Have you checked that the 1520 have the latest Windows version?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching between using the older network standard and the newer on the phone, and then see if you can visit websites using the newer after that.
If that works, then maybe Microsoft (or AT&T since it can be a problem with them) will listen to you if you report that.